# Open multiple projects in Webstorm 10

Tags: webstorm

How can I open more than one project in Webstorm 10, like in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 7):

At the moment it's not possible to open 2+ projects in the same window and still have separate (independent) settings for each of them. To have independent settings you have to open projects in separate frames/windows.

You can "add" files from 2nd/3rd/etc project into main project by attaching that folder as separate node in Project View panel (but current project settings will apply to all of such additional nodes). That can be done via `Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Project | Directories --> Add Content Root`